# Python:Joining lists of uneven sizes without concatenate

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to merge two separate lists:

`x=np.arange(-math.pi/2+0.03079992797, 0, 0.03079992797)` and 
`y=np.arange(0.06159985595,math.pi/2, 0.03079992797)`
normally I would just use `z = np.concatenate((x,y),axis=0)` however I have been instructed not to do so. Is there any other method in which these two lists may be merged?

Comment: `z = np.hstack((x, y))`

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert it to lists and append them:

```
z = array(list(x) + list(y))
```

or try to use list comprehension:

```
np.array([a for a in x] + [b for b in y])
```

Comment: Thanks very much!